# Projective space has no parallel lines.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Define $R  = \mathbb{C}(x_1,x_2,x_3)$. How to see that there are no parallel lines in the projective space $\mathbb{P}^2 = \mathbb{P}^2_\mathbb{C}(v)$. Here we define a *line* as the projective algebraic set $V(ax_1 + bx_2 + cx_3) = \{ ax_1 + bx_2 + cx_3 = 0\}$.

So this is equivalent to saying two distinct lines must intersect (at a point). Does one just argue that $V(ax_1 + bx_2 + cx_3) \cap V(ux_1 + vx_2 + wx_3) = p_0$?

Don't they by definition have a common point at the origin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The origin in $\mathbf{C}^{3}$ doesn't define a point of projective space. Instead, two *planes* in $\mathbf{C}^{3}$ (which project to lines in the projective plane) intersect in a *line* in $\mathbf{C}^{3}$ (which projects to a point). In algebraic terms, a homogeneous system of two linear equations in three unknowns has a non-trivial solution.

Comment: So what does one have to do to see the desired result?

Comment: How exactly you express the argument will depend on your definitions and the available tools (which presumably include results from elementary linear algebra). That aside, I'm not sure where you're stuck. Does the fact of two planes intersecting in a line not help...?

Comment: Well I know what your ideas meant, but I am not sure how to show them mathematically...and what definitions are you not sure of that I did not include?

Comment: If $\ell_{1}$ and $\ell_{2}$ are projective lines, there exist non-zero linear equations cutting them out (by the definition in your question) and the combined homogeneous linear system of two equations in three unknowns cuts out their intersection. I guess my uncertainty is, given that you were able to state the question, what's the obstruction to your writing up this argument in the same notation? Is there something in the notation (or the idea of projective space) you're uncertain about? (In case it helps: Why does the same argument not show that two lines intersect in $\mathbf{P}^{3}$?)

Comment: Well my take was were to just rowreduce...and this produces an answer as you and I conjectured. But i just don't feel it is this technical.

Comment: Well...somehow you have to convert the geometric statement "two lines in the projective plane intersect" into algebra, and then establish some algebraic fact (whose exact nature depends on whether your viewpoint is linear subspaces, varieties, schemes, something else). Observing that "a homogeneous linear system of two equations in three variables has a non-trivial solution" 1. Substantially uses the available hypotheses (compare the situation with lines in $\mathbf{P}^{3}$), and 2. Is about as non-technical a proof as one can imagine. If 2. turns out to be wrong, I'd be delighted to know. :)